# Convertidor romano a decimal

Tags: php

Tengo este código:

```
<?php 
function romano_decimal($var)
{
    $var=strtoupper($var);
    $var=ereg_replace("[^IVXLCDM]","",$var);
    # Definición de variables
    $numeroletrasromanas=array("M"=>1000,"D"=>500,"C"=>100,"L"=>50,"X"=>10,"V"=>5,"I"=>1);
    $parcialfinal=1001;
    for($inicio=0;$inicio<strlen($var);$inicio++)
    {
        $parcial=substr($var,$inicio,1);
        $parcial=$numeroletrasromanas[$parcial];
        if($parcial<=$parcialfinal)
        {
            $suma.="+$parcial";
        }else{
            $suma.="+".($parcial-(2*$parcialfinal));
        }
        $parcialfinal=$parcial;
    }
    eval("\$suma=$suma;");
    return $suma;
}

echo romano_decimal("V");

?>
```

y me da este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg_replace() in C:\xampp\htdocs\convertidor\romaneToDecimal.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\convertidor\romaneToDecimal.php(25): romano_decimal('V') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\convertidor\romaneToDecimal.php on line 5

Comment: saludos te sugiero revisar esto: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php

Comment: que puedo usar en su lugar?

Comment: la solucion es usar : https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php .. .."preg_replace()"..lee la documentacion  y su uso, una vez tengas errores con esto puedes editar tu pregunta y postear la misma [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar esta función que es mucho más simple:

```
function romanToDecimal($roman){
    $result = 0;
    $romans = array(
        'M' => 1000,
        'CM' => 900,
        'D' => 500,
        'CD' => 400,
        'C' => 100,
        'XC' => 90,
        'L' => 50,
        'XL' => 40,
        'X' => 10,
        'IX' => 9,
        'V' => 5,
        'IV' => 4,
        'I' => 1,
    );

    foreach ($romans as $key => $value) {
        while (strpos($roman, $key) === 0) {
            $result += $value;
            $roman = substr($roman, strlen($key));
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

---

Algunas pruebas:

```
echo romanToDecimal('III').PHP_EOL;
echo romanToDecimal('XV').PHP_EOL;
echo romanToDecimal('IV').PHP_EOL;
echo romanToDecimal('XLVIII').PHP_EOL;
echo romanToDecimal('MCMX').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
3
15
4
48
1910
```

---

#### Fuente:

- [Respuesta de @andyb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6266158/5587982) a la pregunta [How to convert a Roman numeral to integer in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6265596/5587982) de Stackoverflow en inglés.

---

### Otra posibilidad

Puedes usar una solución más potente si quisieras, implementando la clase `Numbers_Roman` de la biblioteca Pear.

La puedes incorporar mediante algún gestor de paquetes, o directamente, ya que está bajo una licencia [*version 2.02 de PHP*](https://www.php.net/license/2_02.txt).

El uso sería así:

```
echo Numbers_Roman::toNumber('CCC');
```

**Salida:**

```
300
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay 2 errores en el código, el primero es que al usar PHP mayor o igual a 7.0, debes utilizar la función preg_replace
La segunda es que falta definir la variable $suma, por lo que tendras un error extra.

Te paso el código corregido y probado:

```
<?php 
  function romano_decimal($var)
  {
      $suma=0;
      $var=strtoupper($var);
      $var=preg_replace("[^IVXLCDM]","",$var);
      # Definición de variables 
      $numeroletrasromanas=array(
          "M"=>1000,"D"=>500,"C"=>100,"L"=>50,"X"=>10,"V"=>5,"I"=>1);
      $parcialfinal=1001;
      for($inicio=0;$inicio<strlen($var);$inicio++)
      {
          $parcial=substr($var,$inicio,1);
          $parcial=$numeroletrasromanas[$parcial];
          if($parcial<=$parcialfinal)
          {
              $suma.="+$parcial";
          }else{
              $suma.="+".($parcial-(2*$parcialfinal));
          }
          $parcialfinal=$parcial;
      }
      eval("\$suma=$suma;");
      return $suma;
  }

  echo romano_decimal("MMXIX");

  ?>
```